# Unable to retrieving messages for firebase user

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have no problem creating messages but Im having problems downloading the messages sent to them.

My retrieval code and firebase results stand like so:

```
func MessagesFunc()
{
    let messageDB = Database.database().reference().child("Message").child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!)
    messageDB.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in

        let newMessage = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, String>

        let message = newMessage["Message"]
        let from = newMessage["fromID"]

        let post = ChatMessages()
        post.aMessage = message!
        post.Interested = from!

        print(post.aMessage)
       //no message is printed

       self.messagesArray.append(post)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

[image]

I understand that the database code needs to refer to the child, in this case "Message" and also the current user - uid. However, with no success of retrieval, I'm obviously missing a detail somewhere. I have "Messages" and UID specified but I simply haven't seen tutorials or realized the next steps combining these two ideas into one progressive action. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting up your connection as:

```
...reference().child("Message").child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!)
```

But there is no child with the current user ID under `/Message`. The messages are keyed with push IDs and have user ID properties. You'll need to use queries to get the messages from/to a particular user.

For example, to get the messages sent by the current user:

```
let messageDB = Database.database().reference().child("Message")
let messageQuery = messageDb.queryOrdered(byChild:"fromID").queryEqual(toValue: (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!)
messageQuery.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
```